# Spring boot kafka messaging. How to simplify dto mapping for handlers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I've configured my spring boot project using Kafka. I can receive and publish any string based message.

String message is not the best way for handling. It would be much more useful to have functionality for default converting message from string into object.

Implementing this functionality I've got need to move almost all my Kafka configurations from `yml` to `java` (using property). ...producer example

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AccountSerializer.class);
    return props;
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Account> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, Account> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

The code works, but I accepted simplification. In best case I would like to have elegantly configured `yml`, may be some java changes. But doing it in direct way I'll get additional per 3 beans for configuring each `kafkaTemplate` and `listenerFactory`.

Is it possibly simplify the configurations for the future (I'll need more additional `Serializer``Deserializer`)? How?

### P.S.

I would like configure `yml` in similar way with [this example](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-kafka-and-spring-boot-configuration-example/) :

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      group-id: foo
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

app:
  topic:
    foo: foo.t
```

but I'm not clear how configure here consumers\producers with different (`De`)`Serializer`s, map ones on specified topic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I do not have any chances configure for same listener different `SERIALIZER`|`DESERIALIZER`s.

But id doesn't mean that my issue has no solution.

I've used inheritance for all my objects and provided an abstraction `AbstractEvent`. `AbstractEvent` useless in general but it is used in my solution like enter point for specified `SERIALIZER`|`DESERIALIZER`. To get info which object is in context I've used custom headers. `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer` has no header parameters, but I've implemented my `DESERIALIZER` basing on `ExtendedDeserializer`. This way gives me access to headers

```
via public T deserialize(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] data)
```

example of my **deserializer**:

```
@Slf4j
public class AbstractEventDeserializer<T extends AbstractEvent> implements ExtendedDeserializer<T> {

    private Map<String, Class<T>> mappers = new HashMap<>();

    // default behavior
    @Override
    public T deserialize(String arg0, byte[] devBytes) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        T bar = null;
        try {
            bar = (T) mapper.readValue(devBytes, Bar.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bar;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] data) {
        log.info("handling...");
        headers.forEach(header -> log.info("   {}: {}", header.key(), getHeaderValueAsString(header)));
        Optional<String> classTypeFromHeader = getClassTypeFromHeader(headers);
        if (classTypeFromHeader.isPresent()) {
            return parseFromJson(data, mappers.get(classTypeFromHeader.get()));
        }
        return deserialize(topic, data);
    }

    private Optional<String> getClassTypeFromHeader(Headers headers) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(headers.headers("X-CLASS-TYPE").spliterator(), false)
                .map(Header::value)
                .map(String::new)
                .findFirst();
    }

    private String getHeaderValueAsString(Header header) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(header.value())
                .map(String::new)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> arg0, boolean arg1) {
        log.info("configuring deserialiser");
        if (arg0.containsKey("mappers")) {
            this.mappers = (Map<String, Class<T>>) arg0.get("mappers");
        }
        arg0.keySet().forEach(key -> log.info("   {}:{}", key, arg0.get(key)));
    }

}
```

in case you wanna try working solution, please check [experimental example](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/kafka-examples/tree/master/message-headers).

Answer (score 0):

Spring cloud services allows better configuration for consumers, concurrency, deserialization and less boiler plate code.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Sample of sink

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class LoggingConsumerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(LoggingConsumerApplication.class, args);
}

@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void handle(Person person) {
    System.out.println("Received: " + person);
}

public static class Person {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
}
```

Sample configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: <your topic>
          group: <your consumer group>
          consumer:
            headerMode: raw
            partitioned: true
            concurrency: 10
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: <Comma seperated list of kafka brokers>
```

More information available here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/

Comment: thanks for your time and answer... do you think streaming and event approaches are similar and each can be replaced with other one?

Comment: Streaming is definitely more robust for production systems. You will notice that once your streaming jobs become more complex using the kafka template will become much harder. I would say kafka template is good for very simple use cases.

Comment: I've asked really core question about spring-kafka integration it means i'm new with Kafka. You did not add enough explanation on example. I'm not clear how your copy-past from spring tutorial can help me. In case you sure that your answer is correct please add correspond explanation. Right the particular answer useless for me (and i'm researching more info), sorry.

Comment: Gotcha, Spring cloud services allows for an elegant configuration only approach for kafka and spring. You can set the concurrency (number of consumers) per consumer group which is very helpful. For example if you have a kafka topic with 20 partitions you can set the concurrency up to 20 to allow multiple partitions to be processed in parallel. On the consumer (sink side) spring takes care of the deserialization for you, similar to a rest endpoint. On outgoing message you do have use a serializer though, as all messages are sent as string.

Comment: You can set everything through configuration and use it within the class, this allows configuration based on incoming topics.